# Getting number of active voice connections

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.io

I usually work with discord.js but now I'm contributing to a package that supports discord.io too (it's [dbots.js](https://github.com/EndBug/dbots.js/tree/custom) btw).

I need to post bot stats to [discordbotlist](http://discordbotlist.com)'s API and they support the number of active voice connections too: how can I get it in discord.io?
I've tried searching for properties and method in the [docs](https://izy521.gitbooks.io/discord-io/content/) but I can't find anything like discord.js' [`Client.voiceConnections`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=voiceConnections).

Does anybody know how to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guy the owns the package figured it out:

```
Object.keys(client._vChannels).length
```